# How to split string in batch-file

Tags: windows, batch-file, split

I want to get all the port that running on my windows
I tried

```
for /f "tokens=2" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| findstr LISTENING ^| find "127.0.0.1:"') do @echo %~nxa
```

The results

```
127.0.0.1:2375
127.0.0.1:8884
127.0.0.1:49326
```

How I can get only the ports : ( How I can do split by ":" )

```
2375
8884
49326
```

I tried also

```
    for /f "tokens=2" %e in ('netstat -aon ^| findstr LISTENING ^| find "127.0.0.1:"') do for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %b in ("%e") do @echo %b

but then I got echo also for the command for example
C:\Users\>for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %b in ("127.0.0.1:2375") do @echo %b
2375

C:\Users\>for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %b in ("127.0.0.1:8884") do @echo %b
8884

C:\Users\>for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %b in ("127.0.0.1:40447") do @echo %b
40447

C:\Users\>for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %b in ("127.0.0.1:49326") do @echo %b
49326

C:\Users\>for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %b in ("127.0.0.1:49334") do @echo %b
49334

C:\Users\>for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %b in ("127.0.0.1:51975") do @echo %b
51975

C:\Users\>for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %b in ("127.0.0.1:56502") do @echo %b
56502
```

Comment: Just change **`do for /f`** to **`do @for /f`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure you apply the delimiter check on each item you get from the first for loop you need to write a subroutine as shown below and pass it the value, which is each IP:Port combination you are retrieving.
Then in the subroutine you can extract the value passed in as %1 and then do the split on delimiter.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('netstat -aon ^| findstr LISTENING ^| find "127.0.0.1:"') do (call :subroutine %%a)
:subroutine
   set x=%1
   for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ("%x%") do @echo %%b
```

Comment: The result of x is from netstat -aon ^| findstr LISTENING ^| find "127.0.0.1: so How I can use it in the solution ?

Comment: The above script should do what you are looking for.

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value

Comment: Added some explanation on why the subroutine is needed.